# How to add the same event listener for all my models?

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5.3

Suppose I have the models `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`. Now I want to listen for their `created` event. Usually, I'd go to my `AppServiceProvider` and add the events for each model, like this:

```
public function boot()
{
    A::created(function ($a) {
        //some code
    });

    B::created(function ($b) {
        //some code
    });

    C::created(function ($c) {
        //some code
    });

    D::created(function ($d) {
        //some code
    });
}
```

The code is the same, and I'd like to make that process faster since I actually have 70++ models. So is there a way to bind a single function to the `created` event of all my models without having to do it one by one?

**Edit:** Turns out what I wanted was already in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47670778/how-to-implement-eloquent-saving-event-for-all-models-not-individually), but since it's already been answered I don't want to delete it.

Answer (score 0):

Create a base Model class and Inherit to your models, A, B, C and D. The save method of your base model will fire an event, say, model_create, and you'll be listening for that event only on one place. This way you can handle event for you all of your models.